# Fill Column of SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fill a certain column of a SQL table with data from another table. I have a column named "size" in my table which should return the number of rows in the 2nd table where the id of both rows is the same. Is there a way to populate a SQL column based on a certain command? I would love to be able to fill the column based on this command:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM second_table
WHERE id = "row_id";
```

Here is a sample database with the two tables:

Table 1

| Name | id |
| --- | --- |
| tiger | 1 |
| lion | 2 |
| gazelle | 1 |

Here is the desired output for Table 2:

| id | Number of Animals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I am trying to fill the Number of Animals column but do it automatically and dynamically when another row is added or deleted to Table 1, which is why I want the Select count(*) SQL statement as the code for the column.

Comment: Please provide the sample data as just a copy and paste, instead of malformed ascii art.

Comment: What even is the second table?  Right now, you're basically just running a select on first_table, like ```SELECT id, sum(number_of_animals) as total FROM first_table```.  Do you need it inserted into the second table?  Did you want a view, so the user always sees this, but you don't need the data to "exist" anywhere?  I can think of a few approaches for you, but I need more information about the actual need.

Comment: Your sample data is also wrong.  You say table 1 is ```(name, id)```, and then tiger and gazelle share an id.  You probably mean count, but then you don't have an ID to join on.  It's also unclear to me how you get that desired output at the end, given any interpretation of your Table 1.

Comment: If you want to update the [Number of Animals] field dynamically with new rows being inserted in Tabele 1, then Trigger is the only answer. You got to refresh Table2 every time a row gets inserted in table 1

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 t1
   set size = (select count(*)
               from table2 t2
               where t2.id = t1.id
              );
```

If you need to do this dynamically (as data is inserted), then you would need to use a trigger.  However, I would suggest that you calculate the value as needed, unless there is a specific reason why you need to store it.

Comment: I think requirement is to update the Table2 count based on new rows being inserted in Table 1 dynamically. Trigger would sufice that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAnimalCountTable2
AFTER INSERT ON `Table1` FOR EACH ROW
begin
       DECLARE NewCount int;
       
       SELECT count(1)
       INTO @NewCount
       FROM Table1
       WHERE Table1.id= NEW.id;

       UPDATE Table2
       SET NoOfAnimals = @NewCount
       WHERE id = NEW.id;
       
END;
```

Above is the trigger which will be executed after every insert in Table1 and will update the count in Table 2 for ID which just got inserted in Table1.